# Xelatex created PDF printable standard

Tags: xetex

We are using xelatex for typesetting, and the xelatex will be created direct PDF only. can be the created PDF will be printable standards?

Thanks
Prasad

Comment: Check the pdfx package.

Comment: actually we are using pdfx package, but our query is whether the xelatex created pdf will have any issues while printer stage as we have started analyzing this

Comment: You will have to use preflight or some similar tool to check the document. Nobody here can know if your document is using pdfx correctly (and it is always possible that there is some bug somewhere).

Comment: OK. i.e. xelatex created PDF with preflight will not have any issues in the printer. is n't it.

Comment: It seems like you are asking if postscript based printers which accept an  encapsulated pdf input will always work from a xelatex generated pdf. If so it is not possible to know since 1) every pdf aware printer can handle files differently 2) every XeLaTeX installation can build pdf differently 3) every XeLaTeX author (even a bot) can add/input different items to be compiled on each run. Preflight generally ensures the file is fit for archival storage and standard viewing i.e. not necessarily fit for printing on a specific device.

Comment: i am just checking whether xelatex can be used for typesetting or not? we are using latex+dvips+pdf workflow now, and if we change to xelatex will there be any issues while printer stage even if we use pdfx package and preflight. i would like to check for this.